# Which MBaaS platform to use for a specific project: Parse or Google Cloud

Tags: android, google-app-engine, parse-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, kiicloud

My Android project currently requires an authentication of some sort (mobile phone number / facebook / gmail... I haven't decided yet), frequent read/write operations from the server's db (not a big amount of data, and no images/videos), push notifications and in the future, possibly complex queries on the data stored.

I started reading about [Parse](https://parse.com/) and [Google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/) (in google, specifically about [mobile backend starter](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/)).

I can't seem to find a comparison between the two. I've read that both have relatively easy implementations, but except for the platforms (I'm using Android, so both work for me), I can't find a place that says "Parse is better at ... and Google cloud is better at ...".

So my questions are:

1. Can anyone please give a recommendation / reference?
2. Does one of the above platforms at all fit my project? (I am familiar with AWS, and would like to avoid it so I will not need to worry about stability and scalability)

Comment: Less of an answer, more of adding more to your choices, also look at www.everlive.com, from the Telerik/Kendo team. Very much like Parse, but different in some ways.

Comment: hey dors> What did you finally use?

Comment: I used Parse. They are really easy to work with an integrate into your code

Comment: Another recomendation: [Appery.io](http://goo.gl/m9zOdK). It is a simplified cloud service that enables you to build a mobile application.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug: I'm a developer at [kii.com](http://www.kii.com)

You can also take a look at [Kii Cloud MbaaS](http://www.kii.com)

Among its features:

- User management, including authentication using Facebook credentials.
- Data management that never locks you into any schemas.
- File storage and cloud backup for your app.
- Push notifications so you can push messages to your users or to your
  app itself with updated instructions for functionality.
- Geolocation so you can offer location-based services.
- Server extension to define your own business logic without managing
  servers.
- Android, iOS, html5 and unity support